# How do you verify if an emailing script ran correctly?

Tags: python, email, batch-file

I have written a bat script for robocopying. At the end of the script, it calls upon a python script that is used to send the contents of the log file to an email address. If the python script for one reason or another, didn't end up sending an email, I want to note that by appending a line to the log file. However, I can't seem to find a way within the bat file to check whether the python file ran as expected. This is all being done on windows 7 and the version of python is 2.7.5. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a return code:

In the python script:

```
if email_was_not_sent:
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

In the bat script:

```
# launch the Python script
if errorlevel 1 (
    # Do your logging thing
)
```